PowerAutomate flow failing with "ClientRequest ID....." no matter what I do
I'm very very new to Power Automate, and had a requirement to introduce a sequential approval workflow into a SharePoint List.  I'm using a manual trigger for the flow (to avoid the circular loop issue I was getting using Create/Modify), and I want PowerAutomate to update my Approval Status field depending on whether one of the 5 approvers rejects the item, and it will only be marked Approved if the 5th (final) approver in the sequence approves it.  This all works fine.  My issue is, I'm trying to introduce an Update Item step right at the beginning of the flow, which changes the Approval Status field to Submitted (by default it's Draft).  The Approval Status field is my own choice field, rather than a system-generated field, I don't have content-approval activated on the list, it's purely through Power Automate.
My flow goes:  Manual Trigger > Get Item > Update Item > Start and Wait for An Approval...
As soon as it reaches the Update Item stage, it fails with a ClientRequestID Error and a ServiceRequestID error.  If I remove the Update Item step, it runs through my entire flow (multiple approvals, further Update Item steps etc...) with no problems at all.
I don't understand why it's not failing at the Start and Wait for An Approval stage with this ClientRequestID issue if there's something it's not finding, just at this initial Update Item stage, which then prevents the whole flow continuing.
Any help appreciated!
Have tried introducing an Update Item action, following the first to steps in my flow (Manual Trigger > Get Item).  Have also tried changing the field using a Condition step, but I just get the same ClientRequestID/ServiceRequestID error.
I just need an action as soon as the flow starts, which changes my SharePoint List "Approval Status" choice-field from Draft to Submitted, and then continues through the flow.

It seems that the issue is with the Update Item step failing with a ClientRequestID error. This error occurs when there is a conflict with the item being updated. One possible solution is to add a Condition step before the Update Item step to check if the Approval Status field is already set to "Submitted". If it is, then skip the Update Item step. If not, then update the field to "Submitted". This should prevent any conflicts with the item being updated.
Here is an example flow:
Manual Trigger > Get Item > Condition > Update Item > Start and Wait for An Approval...
In the Condition step, add a condition to check if the Approval Status field is equal to "Submitted". If it is, then skip the Update Item step. If not, then update the field to "Submitted".

Thanks v much. I did actually try that yesterday and still no joy... BUT... I did manage to solve it by using a Send HTTP Request to Sharepoint action instead of Update Item, and put some code in there to update the column to Submitted that way, and it worked! No more CLIENTREQUESTID error, and the whole flow completes as hoped.
